# When I run this, I get a "None" to respond to instead of my question

Tags: python, function

When I run the code, I want the user to respond to the "What do you want?", line. Instead the input line shows up next to "None". Also, PyCharm says something about 'expecting two blank lines, but got 0' in my def shop_interface line. I include the rest of the function, in case I need to put something lower.

I put it in the function block, but I think I'm missing something, I tried putting the item_wanted input into the function, but I think that makes things worse.

```
yes = "yes"
print("Welcome to Python's Shop! What can I do for you?")
item_wanted = input(print("What do you want? Food? Bed?: "))
def shop_interface():
    gold = 200
    if item_wanted == "food":
        print("I have some apples to buy! 20G Each!")
    input("Want them?:")
    if yes:
        gold = gold - 20
        print("You have " + str(gold) + "G left")
    elif item_wanted == "bed":
        print("I have a room for about 15G...want it?")
    elif item_wanted == "weapon":
        print(" There's an old sword in the back, I'll give it to you for 100G.")
    else:
        print("Don't have that, we have food and bed though!")
```

I want the input line to be next to "What do you Want? Food? Bed?" line, instead of none displaying. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Change `input(print("..."))` to `input("...")`.  The `input` function takes a string argument, but you're passing it the return value of `print`, which is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Tom Karzes is right; You should change `input(print("..."))` to `input("...")`. The way you're currently doing it uses the output of print, which is `None`. Your code currently is equivalent to `input(None)`, which is why you've been getting that weird `None`. The correct code would be `input("What do you want? Food? Bed?: ")`.

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
item_wanted = input(print("What do you want? Food? Bed?: "))
```

But that is not going to work as `print` does not return anything. It just prints to the `sys.stdout` (it can also print to a stream) whatever you pass to it.

You should in fact do this

```
item_wanted = input("What do you want? Food? Bed?: ")
```